# Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch when value isnt numerical

Tags: excel, vba, numerical, mismatch

I have the below code that's returning a mismatch error when the value isn't numerical. What would I change?

```
If Sheet3.Cells(4, 8).Value <= 182 Then
    Call ThreeSpells
End If
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Dim MyVar, MyCheck
MyVar = Sheet3.Cells(4, 8).Value
MyCheck = IsNumeric(MyVar) 'Returns True

If MyCheck = True Then
  If Sheet3.Cells(4, 8).Value <= 182 Then
     Call ThreeSpells
  End If
Else
 'msgbox or what you want
End If
```

Comment: Sorry if I've missed something but where does the above code check if the cell value is equal to or less than 182?

Comment: You could condense the code in your answer: `If IsNumeric(Sheet3.Cells(4, 8).Value Then...`